# How to prevent pagebreak for a custom environment?

Tags: page-breaking, environments, mdframed

I use the following custom environment *emailHeader* and [macros to format an email header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/69688/8409)  (credits belong to [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg)).

```
\definecolor{emailHeaderBackground}{RGB}{225,225,225}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  skipabove=0em,
  skipbelow=1em,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor=emailHeaderBackground,
  roundcorner=3pt]
  {emailHeader}
```

In the document ...

```
\begin{emailHeader}
  \emailFrom[John Doe]{john.doe@stackexchange.com}
  \emailSubject{Re: Please do break apart}
  \emailDate{Wed, 22 Aug 2012 12:23:18 +0200}
  \emailTo[Jane Doe]{jone.doe@stackexchange.com}
  \begin{emailsCc}
    \email[Barack Obama]{barack.obama@whitehouse.gov}
    \email[Michelle Robinson]{michelle.robinson@whitehouse.gov}
  \end{emailsCc}
\end{emailHeader}
```

The output looks like this ...

[image: E-Mail header]

I use the environment several hundred times in the document. Sometimes it happens that the email header is at the end or beginning of a page. Then, it breaks into separate lines. As you can see the environment is not a *verbatim* environment for which I found settings to avoid the page break.

**Question:**

How can I prevent a pagebreak for the above environment?
I want the command to be added to the environment definition. I do not want to edit all the places where I use the set of commands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent any environment created by `mdframed` from splitting you can use the option `nobreak=true`. In your case change the definition of `emailHeader` to:

```
\definecolor{emailHeaderBackground}{RGB}{225,225,225}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newmdenv[
  skipabove=0em,
  skipbelow=1em,
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor=emailHeaderBackground,
  roundcorner=3pt,
  nobreak=true]%
  {emailHeader}
```